# Overwrite String variable contents if variable is blank

Tags: java, string, if-statement, jtextfield

I am having trouble with a piece of my program, shown here:

```
String degree1 = degree.getText();

if(degree1 == ""){
   degree1 = "Undergrad";}
```

I want the program to get the text in a textField into a variable, and if that field is blank, to change the contents of the variable to 'Undergrad'

Whenever I test my program, it returns a blank instead of 'Undergrad'

Comment: Compare `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with the `==` operator.

Comment: Note, you could use `if(degree1.isEmpty())`

Comment: Oh damn, I did not see the string comparison question when I was looking for a similar question. Sorry guys, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using `==` for string comparison. Use `if ("".equals(degree1))` instead.

Operator `==` compares references, i.e. it returns `true` for the same object only. If 2 objects are *equal* but not identical `==` returns `false`. This is why class `Object` contains method `equals()` that can (and typically should) be overridden by subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

In Java strings are compared using equals method of String class not == operator